# Rails 6.0: How to print a column value to print a translation locale key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, ruby-on-rails-6

I've made a new controller on the project I'm learning. This controller is called "levels" and each level has a color, a name and an identifier number. The model has only the Number column as integer. Now, since I am doing this using translations, I want to use each number of the column to use my en.yml levels.[number] i did in my localization file to print my translated name in my view depending which language the user is using.

This is how i am trying to do it in the view

`<td><%= level.level %> <%= t('levels. + @level.level') %></td>`

And I cannot print the current value on my en.yml

```
  footer:
    rules: "Rules"
  levels:
    1: blue
    2: green
    3: red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```rb
<%= t('levels')[level.level] %>
```

Where `t('levels')` returns an array of translations, then simply get the expected index

Comment: Actually  <td><%= level.level %> <%= t('levels')[level.level] %></td> did it better